# Symmetric Matrix Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove this problem and I am having trouble were to exactly start. The question is:

> Show that if $A$ is any matrix, then $K = A^T A$ and $L = AA^T$ are both symmetric matrices.

My attempt:

In order to be symmetric then $A=A^T$ then $K = AA$ and since by definition we have that $K = A^n$ is symmetric since $n > 0$.

Comment: If you have matrices $B,C,$ what are $(BC)^T$ and $(B^T)^T?$

Comment: You confuse the variable $A$ in the definition of symmetry with your matrix $A$. Don't do it :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use $(XY)^T=Y^TX^T$. Apply this identity and you'll get it.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. Thank you for your input!

Comment: actually I did not get. I might understand it better if you can tell how to start it off?

Comment: @diimension Let $X=A$ and $Y=A^T$ note that $Y^T=(A^T)^T=A$ hence $(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T$ hence $L=AA^T$ is a symmetric matrix. The proof for $A^TA$ is much the same. The bigger point here is that you need to ask: "what do I need to show?" You need to show $L^T=L$ and $K^T=K$. When you begin by putting $A^T=A$ you assume something about $A$ which was not given... Long was warning you of this pitfall... hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, thank you very much James!